# Configuring Nginx with Traefik

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I'm new to Linux in general, and even newer to Traefik, and have been trying for some time to setup a nginx container to serve some AngularJS web pages, using Traefik as reverse-proxy. I have a small Ubuntu 20.4 server hosted on DigitalOcean (if that's of any relevance).

I have tried following a few different nginx tutorials, and messing with the settings on my own, to no success. It works if I run a simple command like:

> $ docker run –name some-nginx -d -p 8888:80 nginx

But then I can only access it through myip:8888, and I would like to access it with a subdomain, i.e. docs.domain.com.

I managed to setup Traefik using a traefik.yml like that:

```
api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: email@email.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

And then docker-compose this file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`monitor.domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:secret_password"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`monitor.domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

I also successfully set up a portainer:

```
version: '3'

services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    container_name: portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`manage.domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=portainer-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.rule=Host(`manage.domain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.service=portainer"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

This way I can access both portainer and traefik subdomains, with SSL, no problems.

I tried using docker-compose files for nginx similar to the portainer one, using the volumes "./data:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro" and "./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro", as well some different nginx.conf options as exemplified in the [Beginner's Guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure) from the official docs.
I would appreciate if someone could point ou which labels I should use on the docker-compose file and how to properly interface Traefik with the nginx config.